# MySql - INNER JOIN - INDEX

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mariadb

Galera, tô com uma `query` aqui MUITO simples com `JOIN`, devido aos bancos terem muitos registros, preciso indexar...
Mas to apanhando pra kct... Qual a melhor forma de fazer indexar em um `JOIN`? (Essa `query` demora 0.26)

```
SELECT r.* FROM rooms r JOIN users u ON r.owner=u.id WHERE u.id='697' LIMIT 50;
```

Já fiz os seguintes indexs:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_users ON users(username);
CREATE INDEX idx_own ON rooms(owner);
```

Mas nenhum resultado...
Como proceder?

Comment: A única forma que imagino, é se o owner em rooms e id em users são indices, pois username, não tem efeito algum de indexação neste contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Na sua `query` você não está usando a tabela `users` para obter nenhum dado, então você pode alterar seu `SELECT` para:

```
SELECT r.*
  FROM rooms r
 WHERE r.owner = '697'
 LIMIT 50;
```

Assim você terá o mesmo resultado mas sem a necessidade de vincular uma tabela à outra.

Comment: Só peguei uma parte da query para dar exemplo, porque o restante era "indiferente" (visto que, a query estava travando nessa parte)

Comment: @WeversonFernandes fica complicado dar uma resposta sem você dar todos os parâmetros da pergunta...

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém vá consultar aqui futuramente, consegui arrumar:
Minhas tabelas não tinha chaves estrangeiras (criei referente à busca) e um dos campos estava como Varchar(75) sendo que o mesmo armazenava inteiros.
Após a mudança, o tempo da query foi para 0.00